# Repeating a function in regular intervals

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   setInterval(function(){

       setTimeout(function(){

           $('#a').addClass('x');

       },1000);

       setTimeout(function(){

           $('#a').removeClass('x');

       },2000);

   },4000);
```

I was trying to add the class "x" to the div "#a" after 1 s & remove the class after 2 s & repeat the entire function as a loop which executes every 3 s.But the loop worked only once as the time in the setTimeout function did not get incremented after 3 s .So can you help me to make this working.

Comment: the false syntax may be the problemm

Comment: I've closed this as a ***typographical error***. `}),1000;` should be `}, 1000);`, etc.

Comment: I typed wrong while asking the question,but in the actual code it was fine & Not working

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b5122hxn/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have incorrect syntax. also, this can be done without timeouts, just to give you a brief idea:

```
setInterval(function(){
   $("#a").addClass("x").delay(1000).queue(function(next){
     $(this).removeClass("x");
     next();
   });
},6000);
```

[See it in a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5954kvft/)

Comment: Thanks ! It worked ,But if i had to add the class "x" to another div "#b" after the delay of 1000ms & then to remove them from each #a & #b after a delay of 3000ms,do the above mentioned approach holds good ? @Alex

Comment: Glad it worked for you. You can either add another selector or do several actions in the queue function parameter, sure

Answer (score 1):

You have incorrect syntax while setting the interval in both setTimeout and setInterval methods:

```
setInterval(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#a').addClass('x');
   },1000);
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('#a').removeClass('x');
   },2000);
},4000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wtite time period within bracket which corrected in below code.

```
setInterval(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('#a').addClass('x');
       },1000);
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('#a').removeClass('x');
       },2000);
   },4000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/b5122hxn/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to add class x for 1 sec and remove it after another sec. 
You can set the interval to 1 sec and check and remove if element has class otherwise add it.

Below code should work for your prob. you can add a delay of 1 sec if required keeping loop count.

```
setInterval( function(){
       if( $('#a').hasClass('x')){
            $('#a').removeClass('x');
        } else {
            $('#a').addClass('x');
        }
 },1000);
```